# How can I get the values out of onDataChange method?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to compare the user's email who signed in to my app with already registered user's email from my firebase database.

> How can I get the value of `emailFromDatabase` values outside the
>   `onDataChange` method so that I could compare the database's email value to my signed in user's email?

```
usersListDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot emailSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      String emailFromDatabase = (String) emailSnapshot.getValue();
    }
  }
  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

This is the database structure in my Firebase console.

```
amapp-731b2addclose
   + messages
   + version
   - userslist
      - email
         |
         | -- 0: "abc@gmail.com"
         | -- 1: "xyz@gmail.com"
         | -- 2: "ghi@gmail.com"
         | -- 3: "mno@gmail.com"
```

Comment: You can also implement a callback interface to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the value out of the callback. Well... technically you can get it out, but you can't know when that happens.

Instead what you should do is move the code that does the comparison **into** the `onDataChange()` callback. E.g.

```
final String emailFromUser = "pc@somedomain.com";
usersListDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot emailSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      String emailFromDatabase = emailSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
      if (emailFromDatabase.equals(emailFromUser)) {
        System.out.println("Found a matching email");
      }
    }
  }
  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
  }
});
```

To make the code more reusable, you **can** create a custom callback interface. For more on that, see [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519)

Comment: Please see my answer here where you can use the value from datasnapshot outside onDataChange https://stackoverflow.com/a/55741593/3904109